# What ヒネた means here?

Tags: meaning

I am uncertain about the meaning of ヒネた below.

> 子供の中にヒネた大人を捻じ込んだみてーな口調

I understand ヒネた子供 as a child who acts like an adult but I am not sure what ヒネた大人 means. I think it means an adult who got older, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a quote from a recent work, the author might be using ひねた interchangeably with ひねくれた. In that case, it's more about ill-naturedness than about age. This might be technically a misuse of the word, but a rather common one.

I'm not sure if we can say it's definitely a misuse, though, because there can be a continuity from aging to losing innocence to being cynical to having distorted (or ひねくれた) view of the world.

From a lexicographer's tweet:

https://twitter.com/IIMA_Hiroaki/status/211006532517773313

> 「◆ひねた子ども」と聞いて、どんな子を思い浮かべるでしょうか。ませた子どもか、ひねくれた子どもか。正解は前者です。でも、ツイッターでは〈ひねた性格の人〉〈ひねた大人に育ち〉〈ひねた目で見る〉などとあって、圧倒的に後者の意味で使っています。辞書に記述してもいいくらい。

The tweet was about the word's usage among Twitter users in 2012, but I think I see the same thing in a wider Japanese speaking population today.

EDIT: It might not be a recent change, actually. It's easy to find examples [from 1970s](https://dl.ndl.go.jp/search/searchResult?accessRestrictions=internet&accessRestrictions=ooc&accessRestrictions=inlibrary&collection=A00001&collection=A00002&collection=A00022&collection=A00003&collection=A00014&collection=A00015&collection=A00017&collection=A00016&collection=A00019&collection=A00121&collection=A00024&collection=A00152&collection=A00150&collection=A00173&collection=A00122&collection=A00162&collection=B00000&keyword=%22%E3%81%B2%E3%81%AD%E3%81%9F%E5%A4%A7%E4%BA%BA%22&fullText=true&eraType=AD&identifierItem=ISBN&includeVolumeNum=true&pageNum=0&pageSize=20&sortKey=ISSUED_ASC&displayMode=list).

Comment: Very interesting to see how words are changing over time.

Answer (score 2):

This ヒネた is from type II or 下一段【しもいちだん】 verb 陳【ひ】ねる, which basically just means "to age, to put on years, to grow older".  Used euphemistically and in the past tense / completed aspect (as when talking about a child's manner), it can mean something closer to "to seem older than one's years".

In your sample sentence, I think ヒネた大人 just means "an older adult".

Bilingual (albeit very minimal) entry:

- [Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E9%99%B3%E3%81%AD%E3%82%8B)

If you can read Japanese, entries at Kotobank for:

- [Daijisen](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%99%B3%E3%81%AD%E3%82%8B-612003)
- [Nihon Kokugo Dai Jiten](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%99%B3-569830)

Comment: You probably meant 下**一**段, not 下**二**段. 下二段 verb would have 終止形 = 陳ぬ and 連体形 = 陳ぬる.

Comment: Not sure of the exact context here, but I feel like the meaning is more likely to be this slang meaning: ③〔俗〕ひねくれる。
「ひねた性格を直したい」
［表記］俗に「ヒネる」とも。

Comment: @Arfrever - doh!  I spend so much time with classical that I brain-farted in writing the post here.  I'll fix that.  Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, interesting! Didn't see that sense in my refs. What site/dictionary is that from?

Comment: @DariusJahandarie My initial reading of the sentence was the same. I believe you are right.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi 三省堂国語辞典第八版

Comment: I was also confusing ヒネる and ひねくれる... Regardless of which meaning it had, ヒネた大人 would refer to a person who is overly argumentative and difficult to deal with.